# Getting Faraday::Error::TimeoutError when creating card in Balanced gem

Tags: ruby, balanced-payments, faraday

I am using the [Balanced ruby gem](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby) in my rails app for payment integration.

I am submitting card information and getting valid response. Then I send card information to my controller and in that I am creating buyer using `card_uri`.

```
buyer = Balanced::Marketplace.my_marketplace.create_buyer(@member.email, card_uri)
```

but, I am getting this error:

```
Faraday::Error::TimeoutError (execution expired):
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you turn on debug logging and give us the header outputs? To do so, just configure your Balanced gem client with `Balanced.configure(:api_key, :logger => Rails.logger)` and set your logging level to DEBUG

Answer (score 10):

I've done some more digging in this issue, it could be that it's a transient network slowness. The settings are pretty strict for Faraday, so maybe we can loosen them up a bit.

When configuring Balanced, try this:

```
Balanced.configure('API_KEY_STRING', :connection_timeout => 30, 
                                     :read_timeout => 30)
```

Hope this helps.